# SocketError : Operation not permitted (returning py2neo exception)

Tags: python, django, py2neo, neomodel

I am trying to return a bunch of rows to my web page with a render function in django, but I get the following error.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/neoapp/user_rec.html

Django Version: 1.8.6
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'neoapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\dev\web\project\neoapp\views.py" in user_rec
  19.           m = graph.cypher.execute("""MATCH    (b:User)-[r:HAS_RATED]->(m:Movie), (b)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(a:User {userID:"""+str(uid)
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py" in cypher
  667.             metadata = self.resource.metadata
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py" in metadata
  213.             self.get()
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py" in get
  258.             response = self.__base.get(headers=headers, redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py" in get
  966.         return self.__get_or_head("GET", if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py" in __get_or_head
  943.         return rq.submit(redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py" in submit
  433.             http, rs = submit(self.method, uri, self.body, self.headers)
File "C:\dev\web\neo\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py" in submit
  362.             raise SocketError(code, description, host_port=uri.host_port)

Exception Type: SocketError at /neoapp/user_rec.html
Exception Value: Operation not permitted
```

The **views** file is -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from neomodel import StructuredNode, StructuredRel, RelationshipTo, RelationshipFrom, StringProperty, IntegerProperty, DateTimeProperty
from models import *
from forms import UserForm
from py2neo import *

def user_rec(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # return render(request,'got_it.html',{
            #   'message':request.POST['userid']
            #   })
            uid = request.POST.get("userid")

            graph = Graph("https://neo4j:goel@localhost:7474/db/data/")

            m = graph.cypher.execute("""MATCH    (b:User)-[r:HAS_RATED]->(m:Movie), (b)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(a:User {userID:"""+str(uid)
    +"""}) WHERE    NOT((a)-[:RATED]->(m)) WITH m, s.similarity AS sim, r.rating AS rating ORDER BY m.name, rating DESC WITH m.name AS movie, 
COLLECT(rating)[0..3] AS ratings WITH movie, REDUCE(s = 0, i IN ratings | s + i)*1.0 / LENGTH(ratings) AS reco  ORDER BY reco DESC
RETURN   movie AS Movie, reco AS Recommendation limit 10""")

            return render(request,'reco.html',{
                'm': m
                })

    else:

        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'user_rec.html', {'form': form})
```

Why am I getting this **py2neo** exception? How can I otherwise run a query in my views.py file?

Comment: That's a py2neo exception? `SocketError : Operation not permitted`?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see the stacktrace now. It is a py2neo exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce this by using the https protocol instead of http.

```
>>> from py2neo import Graph
>>> graph = Graph("https://localhost:7474/db/data/")
>>> m = graph.cypher.execute("match n return n limit 5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 659, in cypher
    metadata = self.resource.metadata
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 213, in metadata
    self.get()
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 258, in get
    response = self.__base.get(headers=headers, redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 966, in get
    return self.__get_or_head("GET", if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 943, in __get_or_head
    return rq.submit(redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 433, in submit
    http, rs = submit(self.method, uri, self.body, self.headers)
  File "/Users/nicolewhite/Envs/science/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 362, in submit
    raise SocketError(code, description, host_port=uri.host_port)
py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: Operation not permitted
>>>
```

So you can either switch to http or check out the docs on https support. http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#security-server-https

Comment: oh, I read about that yesterday. Still ran into it. Thanks very much !